# Replacing names with X in thousands of text files

Tags: text, replace

I do not know anything about programming.

1. I have thousands of text files (.txt), in each of them person names are included. I have these names in a column in a separate spreadsheet too. I want to replace all this names with a "X". So instead of "Brad pitt" or "Angelina Jolie" or "George Clooney", all will be replaced by "X". Is it possible to do it in a few step approach instead of opening every file and replacing the names?
2. I have a 7 character string of numbers in each of these files, say 1234567 or 1234568. Again is it possible to replace all these nembers in all these files to just a "X"?

Please guide me what program in windows can I use to do these?
Accept my apology for lay computer language.

Answer (score 0):

Download notepad++, http://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v6.3.html
Click on top, search > find (or ctrl+f)
click the find in files tab
select the directory, fill out the find what and replace with
click replace in files

Edit: "I did, but the problem is that in "find what", I can put one name, but I have a list of 1000 different first and last names to be replaced with X (I mean de-identifying)"

In that case I would write a C# program to read in all the files, file by file and loop through your list of names. Use the String.Replace method to replace the names with X and then save the file. Look at the StreamReader and StreamWriter classes.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx

Comment: I did, but the problem is that in "find what", I can put one name, but I have a list of 1000 different first and last names to be replaced with X (I mean de-identifying).

Comment: Updated my answer, hopefully you know a little about programming.